# IOS Button border thickness lssue,why？

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-ui-automation

`UIButton` ***top border appears thicker than the following ,but sometimes correct*** ，why?

code:

```
 UIImage * sanImage = [UIimage imageNamed:@"product_bt1_normal"];
 [self.saveBtn setBackgroundImage:[sanImage 
 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:sanImage.size.width/3   
 topCapHeight:sanImage.size.height/3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

Comment: image: [address](http://112.124.102.135/11.png)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make a button?  If so, perhaps use a UIButton instead?  You can control the border with `button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f`

If you're set on using an image, create a UIImageView, and modify the border thickness that way:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:sanImage];
[iv.layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];
```

Comment: saveBtn is UIButton，Is a random problem The following will be rough sometimes be some

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of off-pixel boundaries. Since you are using height/3.0f, your image is maybe not returning a well-behaved image.

Also, there is a new stretchable image method you should be using, resizableImageWithCapInsets:.

So try this code out:

```
[self.saveBtn setBackgroundImage:[sanImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You might need to mess with the values for the insets a bit, I don't know the dimensions of your button image.

Comment: thankyou ,But still there is a problem   'product_bt1_normal' image address [link](http://112.124.102.135/product_bt1_normal@2x.png), BUT IOS6 no problem